# overflow: how to make a table scroll only on x axis?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a table, with such and such columns. I want to avoid the table overflowing outside the window, so I wrap it with a div:

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table> 
        <!-- etc. -->
    </table>
</div>
```

and I give that div the following CSS:

```
.table-wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

It worked very well for a while. But then I needed a table with column of `<select>` elements. In that case, *I don't want* the table to scroll, and I prefer the select to go outside the wrapper (instead of an uncomfortable inner scroll). I thought splitting it up to x and y would be it:

```
.table-wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

But apparently not. For some reason, `overflow-y` isn't taken into consideration and the table still uses a scroll for the y axis. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvii/rh4pugcp/4/) showing this. here's the desired behavior

1. the first table **should not** scroll downwards, instead it should be visible
2. the second table **should** scroll sideways
3. And of course, the third table should combine the two - it **should scroll on the x-axis** and it **shouldn't scroll on the y-axis** (have it `visible`)

What's the solution here?

**update**

It seems that [the `visible` value is a lie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/2387772):

> If you are using `visible` for either `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` and
>   something other than `visible` for the other. The `visible` value is
>   interpreted as `auto`.

It's like a recessive gene, it only works if everything else is `visible`, and if you define the other axis as anything else it automatically conforms to `auto` because `W3C` hates making any sense, and loves making my life a lot harder.

So now it seems the answer I'm looking for is a hacky workaround of sorts (and unless there's absolutely no other option, using specific pixels for either width or height is not an accepted solution. Com'on, I need to be a *tad* more flexible than that)

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
    .table-wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto; //allows the div to scroll horizontally only when the div overflows.
    overflow-y: hidden; //does not allow for the div to scroll vertically
}
```

Comment: But that makes it hidden. I want it `visible` (I want the user to *see* the select opening below the table)

Answer (score 0):

you can scroll along x-axis even when overflow hidden using jquery.
This code will scroll x-axis.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {

   $("YourSelector").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

      event.preventDefault();

   });

});
</script>
```

Comment: That's a nice thought, if only `hidden` would work with `visible` - but that's the problem! if I do `overflow-x: hidden` with `overflow-y: visible` then x-axis is hidden, but y-axis is still `auto`, i.e a *scroll*